# Protecting against Slow POST attack in Azure Web Role

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

Received security testing report for our service, which is hosted as Web Role in Azure. One of the points is vulnerability to Slow POST attack. The recommendations are mostly for configuring IIS, which we cannot do here. There is reference to some SiteExtentions that applies to Azure Web Site. But we don't use Web Site, we use Web Role.

Any suggestions what can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can use startup tasks defined in your web role to run programs that will customize IIS after the VM hosting your app has been created.

See [this MSDN article on startup tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg433059.aspx) and [this blog post](http://mvolo.com/configure-iis-websites-windows-azure-startup-tasks-appcmd/).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that many IIS settings can be controlled via web.config sections these days (as long as the host doesn't lock them down). In the event that you can't change the nodes because they are locked, then you need to script the change and host start as others have mentioned.

Looking at [Security Labs](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2011/11/02/how-to-protect-against-slow-http-attacks) and their advice on IIS 7 at least some of the confing nodes they link to are held in the web.config:

- Request Limits: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits
- Header Limits:
  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/headerlimits